# Rendering an object with a multi-indexed property onto a 2d grid layout

Tags: wpf

As the title says, I am looking for some advise on how I can render the content of an object with a multi-indexed property onto a 2d grid-like UI element.

The data I am trying to render is manifested in a table-grid alike datastructure consisting of n rows and m columns, following a sparse matrix ADT (see http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/creating-a-sparse-matrix-in-net). Each [row, column] pair returns a cell value. When working with the table-grid structure I can set and get values at row '0' and column '0' by using an indexer such that tableGrid[0, 0] (which returns the element at the first row and column). For simplicity, the element returned is of type object which contains the value of that specific cell, where the number of rows and columns are known.

Based on the article http://geekswithblogs.net/btudor/archive/2009/05/31/132526.aspx, I've so far been able to bind a textbox to the value of a single [row, column] pair (in the example shown below, the value of [1,1]), thus allowing the UI to update the table-grid back and forth.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBlock5" Text="{Binding [1\,1], Mode=TwoWay />
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TableGridViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly TableGrid _grid;        

    public object this[int row, int col]
    {
        get { return _grid[row, col]; }
        set
        {
            _grid[row, col] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
        }
    }

    public TableGridViewModel()
    {
        _grid = new TableGrid();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                _grid[i, j] = i * j;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

The question is how one can create a 2D grid which can represent all the values found at each [row, column] in the table-grid (i.e. a 10 x 10 matrix), meaning both displaying and updating it back and forth through the indexer property of the view-model.

Any thoughts?

~ E.

Comment: Well, sort of... It was possible to do it using a multi-binding. But it was not really a good solution, so we ended up using a completely different strategy. So my advise, don't pursue this path, it will only give you a hard time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience